# routing for asp.net web api along with odata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

My asp.net web application is hybrid which can have all different types of controllers -

1. asp.net MVC controllers (derived from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`)
2. asp.ner Web API controllers (derived from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`) and
3. asp.net based OData controllers (derived from `System.Web.Http.OData.ODataController`)

I am trying to configure routing in `WebApiConfig.cs` for Web API and OData controllers and it looks something like this -

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("OData", "odata", CreateEdmModel());

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}

public static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Detail>("Details");
            return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

routes that work -

1. api/Values/GetSummary (for `ASP.Net Web API` based `ValuesController` with `GetSummary` aciton method)
2. Home (for regular asp.net MVC `HomeController`)

routes that doesnt work-

1. odata/Summary
2. odata/Summary/GetSummary

My regular MVC controllers execute fine, Web API controllers also work fine, but somehow routing is not working for OData controllers. Has anyone tried mix and match in a single application and able to make it work? I will also need to specify action method name in the route, since all action method are mostly `GET` since it is a reporting application.

Comment: Can you post the code for your SummaryOdataController I think the issue could be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to mix all these controllers. If MVC's routing was activated first in Global.asax.cs then MVC's default route may not allow to reach OData controllers. 
Changing the order of lines in Global.asax.cs as shown below will solve the issue. MVC controllers routing is usually setup in RouteConfig.cs , Web API and OData routing in WebAPIConfig.cs if project templates were used.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // moved up before MVC's setup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```